# SAS import problem with utf-8 and u+2019 character

Tags: import, utf-8, sas

I am trying to import a value from a csv, using an input statement with encoding at utf8.
The value contains a u+2019 character, which sas doesn't recognize at all and displays a box instead.

Anyone knows what could the problem be?

Comment: Is your SAS session running using UTF-8 encoding?  Check the value of the ENCODING option.

Comment: Yes, its running in utf8, also i make sure that i put that again in the input statement as the encoding option. It imports everything perfectly except the right apostrophe, which i think is the  U+2019 character. When i open the file normally with notepad, the apostrophe is displayed correctly.

Comment: How are you running SAS? Display Manager? SAS/Studio? Enterprise Guide? How are you reading the file?  data step or PROC IMPORT?  How are displaying the file? SAS Log or Listing output or ODS output like HTML or PDF?

Comment: SAS enterprise guide. its a data step with a length, label, infile and input statement. At the infile i added the following options: dlm=';' missover dsd encoding='utf-8'. I am just opening the table in sas enterprise guide, no special display

Comment: With EG you have to connect to a SAS session for it to run the code. How is the ENCODING option set in that session? You can use PROC OPTIONS to check.  If it is not UTF-8 then you need connect to a differently configured session. Which might mean setting up a different SAS application server for EG to connect to.

Comment: You are correct. The encoding is set to LATIN1. but after program runs in log there is: ods tagsets.sasreport is set at encoding ='UTF8' but this is concerned only for the output correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session needs to be running UTF8, otherwise SAS will try to transcode the text into the session encoding.  Ask your SAS admin to show you how to connect to an application server that is running using UTF8 encoding.